# My tic tac toe game (jquery) is not working properly. Lost Part is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The 'Win' and 'Draw' parts are showing up on time, but the 'Lost' part doesn't show the message 'you lost'until I click on an empty cell once again. Please check out my code and help me find any errors.

Below is my code:

Marked is a class that changes the opacity of the clicked cell.
1,2,3...are the id's of respective cells in the table(html).

I tried delay() too instead of setTimeout(), but it didn't work as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer;
    var x = 0;
    $("td").click(function() { 
        if($(this).text()=='') {
            $(this).text("0").addClass("marked");
            x = 1;
        } 
    }).click(function() { 
        if(x==1) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                var choose = $("td").not(".marked");
                var random = choose[Math.floor(Math.random()*choose.length)];
                $(random).text("X").addClass("marked");
            },1000);
            x=0;
            showResult();
        }
    });
    function showResult() { 
        var one = $("#1").text();
        var two = $("#2").text();
        var three = $("#3").text();
        var four = $("#4").text();
        var five = $("#5").text();
        var six = $("#6").text();
        var seven = $("#7").text();
        var eight = $("#8").text();
        var nine = $("#9").text();
        if(one==two && two==three)
            result(one)
        else if (four==five && five==six) 
            result(four)
        else if(seven==eight && eight==nine)
            result(seven)
        else if (one==four && four==seven) 
            result(one)
        else if (two==five && five==eight)
            result(two)
        else if (three==six && six==nine) 
            result(three)
        else if (one==five && five==nine) 
            result(one)
        else if(three==five && five==seven)
            result(three);
        else {
            var z = $("td").not(".marked");
            if(z.length == 0) {
                $("p").text("Draw!");
                $("td").removeClass("marked");
                $("td").text("");
                $("#demo1").append('<img src="https://media.tenor.com/images/54c63f726505bfdb455eb4c29e626ad8/tenor.gif">');
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
        } 
    } 
    function result(y) {
        var result = y;
        if(result=="X"){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $("p").text("You Lost!");
            $("td").removeClass("marked");
            $("td").text("");
            $("#demo1").append('<img src="https://media.tenor.com/images/08902a85a6107684f8614846f4a54218/tenor.gif">');
        }
        if(result=="0") {
            $("td").text("");
            $("p").text("You Won!");
            $("#demo1").append('<img src="https://i.gifer.com/4OuC.gif">');
            $("td").removeClass("marked");
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling showResult immeadiately when the user clicked, so it cant't recognize the X put into the table one second later.

Just do:

```
$("td").click(function() {
    [...]
}).click(function() {
    if (x == 1) {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            var choose = $("td").not(".marked");
            var random = choose[Math.floor(Math.random() * choose.length)];
            $(random).text("X").addClass("marked");

            /******** ADD ANOTHER CHECK HERE ********/
            showResult();
        }, 1000);
        x = 0;
        showResult();
    }
});
```

It might also be a good idea to add a return to showResult that returns false when a result was achieved. This way you could do something like

```
x = 0;
if (showResult()) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        [...]
    }
}
```

And the user can't get a loose message right after a win message.

Also: Why do you need the 2 click listeners? You can just use the if statement in the top one and then you don't need the `(x ==  1)`